# Fonts required for mPDF

Tags: php, fonts

I need few fonts files for mpdf.

- Arial
- Verdana
- Times New Roman
- Courier New
- Tamoha
- Goergia
- Trebuchet MS

If anybody have please share with me

Answer (score 2):

For 4.x, [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=409&searchstring=fonts) is an explanation how to convert TrueType fonts into MPDF's format.

There is also a Beta for mpdf 5 that can read TrueType Fonts directly.

As symcbean says, be aware of possible licensing issues. These fonts come for free with every Windows installation, but they are not necessarily free to distribute.

Answer (score 1):

For non-Microsoft systems, these fonts are available via the build package [here](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/).

The licensing of the fonts is a complex and somewhat sordid story - but since the [initial release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web) preadtes UCITA (which has limited applicability anyway) you can still legitimately download and use the software under the original Microsoft EULA

C.

Comment: +1 for mentioning licensing issues.